# how to get month value against number?

Tags: android

My code returns the current month as a number, for instance, if the month is July, the code will display 7 (see image link).
http://imgur.com/Rvf8QYp
How do I print the months name against its number?

```
 public void showOnScreen() {


    date_today.setText(mYear + "Years" + mMonth + "Month");
    e00.setText("" + a[0][0]);
    e01.setText("" + a[0][1]);
    e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);
    e03.setText("" + a[0][3]);
    e04.setText("" + a[0][4]);
    e05.setText("" + a[0][5]);
    e06.setText("" + a[0][6]);

}
```

Comment: no  i get month in number i  want to print month nae against its number  in this variable mMonth

Comment: howi use like if (mMonth =1{mMonth ==January} or use switch case what i used and how???

Comment: Why don't you read the answers to the question I linked?

Comment: you can use switch cases to get month name based on its number

Comment: how????????? i did if (mMonth ==1) 
  { 
   Monthname="January";
   }
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int
 - Syntax error on token "==", invalid 
  AssignmentOperator

Comment: @persianDev: rough solution, but it works.  For elegance, lift the code into a method like monthToString and handle appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the Java.util.Calendar class the method [getDisplayName](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29):

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
String date_plaintext = calendar.getDisplayName(mMonth, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
date_today.setText(date_plaintext+ ", " + mYear);
```